# Creating separate views for related data in Django

Tags: python, html, django

Hello all I am attempting allow a user to use a electronic medical records software to create a patient instance using a form and have the instance created displayed on a seperate page that can be accessed via the `see patient` link.

> This is code for my views.py

I created the `Identity_view` class based view that is rendered via the nesting.html

I used both the `GET` and `POST` methods to get the unbounded form and post the bounded form to the server and save to the database.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from nesting.forms import Identity_Form
from nesting.models import Identity_unique

class Identity_view(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'nesting/nesting.html'

    def get(self, request):

        form = Identity_Form()

        Identities = Identity_unique.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        var = {'form': form, 'Identities': Identities}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

    def post(self, request):

        form  = Identity_Form(request.POST or None)

        content = None

        if form.is_valid():

            NIS = form.save(commit = False)
            NIS.user = request.user
            NIS.save()
            content = form.cleaned_data['NIS']

            form = Identity_Form()

            return redirect('nesting:nesting')

        var = {'form': form, 'content': content}

        return render(request,self.template_name, var)
```

> This is the nesting.html document

Currently this section of my code is on the same page as the form that is used to create the patient instances.

```
      {% block body %}

            {% for Identity in Identities %}

            <div class = "row">

              <div class="col-sm"></div>

              <div class = "col-sm">
                <div class = "card " style = "margin-top: 40px;">
                        <ul class = "list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class = "list-group-item"><a class = "nav-link" href="#">{{Identity.First_Name}}  {{Identity.Last_Name}} </a></li>
                          <li class = "list-group-item"><small><br>NIS: </small> {{ Identity.NIS }}</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

              </div>
            <div class="col-sm"></div>
            </div>
                      {% endfor %}


    {% endblock %}
```

This is an image of the current state of the templates :

[image]

In the image above I want the card lists created beneath the form to be rendered to the page that can be accessed by the `see patient` navigation link in the side menu. I have already created the HTML template in the subfolder I create in the `templates` folder. I just want to ensure the patient data is displate using the templating language on a seperate page.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display patient's card lists on a separate page that can be accessed via the see patient link you need to make another view in which you will fetch all the patients created by logged in user.

```
class IdentityListyView(ListView):
    model = Identity_unique
    template_name = 'templates/identity_list.html' # your template to show  patients list

    def get_identities(self):
        identities = self.model.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return identities

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        First create context with the required context_data then update the context with super.
        '''
        context = dict()
        context['Identities'] = self.get_identities()
        context.update(super(IdentityListyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs))
        return context
```

you can access `Identities` in your template to display patients list as you have done in `nesting/nesting.html`

Comment: @PaulDixit Thank you for the help. Question: Is the `identities` in `identities = self.model.objects.filter(user=request.user)` the same as the `Identities` in
`context['Identities'] = self.get_identities()`?

Comment: @WalthamWECAN yes. `get_identities` is method of class `IdentityListyView` and thus can be accessed by self.

Comment: @WalthamWECAN if you find this answer helpful  up-vote and accept it.